# Passing an empty object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have some select boxes that ask for the number of children and then how old the children are.

I have made an object in my form for this. However because the object is already created it is expecting something so if no children are selected the children's age object is still passed.

I have tried just passing null or bool into my object but it is messing around with my scope elements as I have it reading back from the session.

So at the moment it is just passing an empty object.

Is this bad for security? I understand for best practice something should be passed? If anything it is expecting a key:value

If `numberOfChildren === 0`, can I delete the object? Or what else can I pass?

**Object that gets saved as a session**

```
 var achSearch = {
    destination: destination,
    arrivalDate: arrivalDate,
    departureDate: departureDate,
    numberOfAdults: $scope.achSearch.numberOfAdults,
    numberOfChildren: $scope.achSearch.numberOfChildren,
    childAges:childAges
  }
```

**Passing into object**

```
if($scope.achSearch.numberOfChildren == 0){        
   achSearch.childAges = null;
}
else if($scope.achSearch.numberOfChildren == 1){        
   achSearch.childAges.child1 = $scope.achSearch.childAges.child1;
}
else if($scope.achSearch.numberOfChildren == 2){        
   achSearch.childAges.child1 = $scope.achSearch.childAges.child1;
   achSearch.childAges.child2 = $scope.achSearch.childAges.child2;
}
```

**The object**

```
"numberOfChildren":"2","childAges":{"child1":"4","child2":"4"}
```

Comment: Would be helpful to see some code

Comment: Post your code, otherwise you are asking a very general question which may be hard to visualise.

Comment: Try `delete achSearch.childAges` instead of `achSearch.childAges = null`. However there is no a security issue with saving empty object.

Comment: delete achSearch.childAges worked thanks